# log RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, indexing, range

I  am trying to get the registered contacts on App but it only shows the list of contacts in the Phone and not the Registered ones on the App and firebase....

here is the Contacts Page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/extension/custom_theme_extension.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/feature/contacts/controllers/contact_controller.dart';
import '../../../common/utils/coloors.dart';
import '../../../common/widgets/custom_icon_button.dart';
import '../widgets/contact_cards.dart';

class ContactPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ContactPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  shareSmsLink(phoneNumber) async {
    Uri sms = Uri.parse(
      "sms:$phoneNumber?body=Let's chat on WhatsApp! it's a fast, simple,"
          " and secure app we can call each other for free. Get it at https://whatsapp.com/dl/",
    );
    if (await launchUrl(sms)) {
    } else {

    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    //debugPrint('Building ContactPage');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(),
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Select Contact',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 3,),
            ref.watch(contactControllerProvider).when(
                data: (allContacts){
      //            debugPrint('Fetched allContacts: $allContacts');
                  return Text("${allContacts[0].length} contact${allContacts[0].length == 1 ? '' : 's'}");
                },
                error: (e,t){
                  return const SizedBox();
                },

                loading: (){
                  return const Text(
                    'counting...',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                  );
                },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          CustomIconButton(onTap: (){}, icon: Icons.search,),
          CustomIconButton(onTap: (){}, icon: Icons.more_vert,),
        ],
      ),
      body: ref.watch(contactControllerProvider).when(
          data: (allContacts){
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: allContacts[0].length + allContacts[1].length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){

                  late UserModel firebaseContacts;
                  late UserModel phoneContacts;
                 //^^^ debugPrint('Building ContactCard at index: $index');


                  if(index < allContacts[0].length){
                  debugPrint("Working");
                  firebaseContacts = allContacts[0][index];
                } else {
                  phoneContacts = allContacts[1][index - allContacts[0].length];
                  //debugPrint("not working");
                  }
                return index < allContacts[0].length
                    ? Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    if(index == 0)
                       Column(
                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                         children: [
                              myListTile(
                                  leading: Icons.group,
                                  text: "New Group",
                              ),
                              myListTile(
                                text: "New Contact",
                                leading: Icons.qr_code,
                              ),
                           Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20,
                                vertical: 10,
                              ),
                            child: Text(
                              'Contacts on Whatsapp',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: context.theme.greyColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                      ),
                         ],
                       ),
                    ContactCard(
                        contactSource: firebaseContacts,
                        onTap: (){},
                    )
                  ],
                )
                    : Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    if(index == allContacts[0].length)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20,
                          vertical: 10,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          'Contacts on Whatsapp',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: context.theme.greyColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ContactCard(contactSource: phoneContacts,
                      onTap: () => shareSmsLink(phoneContacts.phoneNumber)),
                  ],
                );

                } );
          },
          error: (e,t){
            return null;
          },

          loading: (){
            return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: context.theme.authAppBarTextColor,
                )
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  ListTile myListTile({
  required IconData leading,
  required String text,
  IconData? trailing,
  }){
    return ListTile(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 20,
        backgroundColor: Coloors.greenDark,
        child: Icon(
          leading,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      title: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
        trailing,
        color: Coloors.greyDark,
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

This condition does not run as it says that there is no contact on the index while they are registered on the Firestore

```
 if(index < allContacts[0].length){
 firebaseContacts = allContacts[0][index];
                }
```

The contact Repository code is given as well if it helps you identify the problem

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_contacts/flutter_contacts.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_clone/common/models/user_model.dart';

final contactsRepositoryProvider = Provider(
      (ref) {
    return ContactsRepository(firestore: FirebaseFirestore.instance);
  },
);

class ContactsRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  ContactsRepository({required this.firestore});

  Future<List<List<UserModel>>> getAllContacts() async {
    List<UserModel> firebaseContacts = [];
    List<UserModel> phoneContacts = [];

    try {
      if (await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
        final userCollection = await firestore.collection('users').get();
        final allContactsInThePhone = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(
          withProperties: true,
        );
        //debugPrint('Total Contacts in Phone: ${allContactsInThePhone.length}');

        bool isContactFound = false;

        for (var contact in allContactsInThePhone) {

          //debugPrint('Processing Contact: ${contact.displayName}');
          for (var firebaseContactData in userCollection.docs) {
          var firebaseContact = UserModel.fromMap(firebaseContactData.data());
          //debugPrint('Comparing with Firebase Contact: $firebaseContact');
            if (contact.phones[0].number.replaceAll(' ', '') ==
                firebaseContact.phoneNumber) {
              firebaseContacts.add(firebaseContact);
              isContactFound = true;
              //debugPrint('Firebase Contact Found: $firebaseContact');
              break;
            }
          }
          if (!isContactFound) {
            phoneContacts.add(
              UserModel(
                username: contact.displayName,
                uid: '',
                profileImageUrl: '',
                active: false,
                phoneNumber: contact.phones[0].number.replaceAll(' ', ''),
                groupId: [],
              ),
            );
          }

          isContactFound = false;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }

    return [firebaseContacts, phoneContacts];
  }
}
```

I was expecting the Registered Contact list to appear as i have already registered 2-3 contacts that are saved in my device.